# Getting href of not only first but all matched elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the code below I only get the `href` of the first matched element.

```
$("a.item").attr("href")
```

How can I get the `href` of all matched elements?

Comment: Can you add corresponding HTML also

Comment: how many href's you have?

Comment: Maybe a loop? `$("a.item").each(function() { $(this).attr("href"); }); `

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown for (i=0; i<$("a.item").length) {mylist = $("a.item").attr("href")}  but it didn't work.

Comment: @Alni `$("a.item").eq(i).attr("href")`  You should start trying to understand how a css/jq selector works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map it to get an array:

```
var hrefs = $("a.item").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href'); // or this.href (returning absolute path)
}).get();
```

Comment: anchor tag must have only one href attribute. Sorry about the downvote but that does not fit the given w3c standards.

Comment: Can you explain `.get()` ?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal You didn't understand this snippet then

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal It isn't multiple attributes in one element, but multiple elements.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown `get()` is to return a true array, not jq object and so you can use any relevant array prototype method on it

Comment: The OP has got multiple href's I guess.. Sorry about that. Did not go through the snippet completely

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Ok i see what you mean but that's not how i understood issue. It more lloks like OP as multiple `a.item` and want to get all href for all these items

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal Now rereading the question, it is completly unclear indeed